# Windows 8.1 update unsuccessful

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I can't successfully perform a complete scan using Windows update on my system. The scan is running endlessly, no errors and no timeout.

I have used the Microsoft repair tool WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab three times and every time it repairs the two following points:

- Missing or corrupted registration service
- Last updates installation problems

I'm not sure repairing is really effective because it detects the same errors each time.

I try the updates with a powershell script, but it seems to run endlessly too. Finally I stop it manually without any message from it.

Here is my windows update log:

```
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.9.9600.16422, tz: +0200)  ===========
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Misc      = Module: c:\windows\system32\wuaueng.dll
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Service *************
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Service ** START **  Service: Service startup
2015-06-02  10:48:00:597     932    7b0 Service *********
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Agent     * WU client version 7.9.9600.16422
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Agent     * Base directory: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Agent     * Access type: No proxy
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  10:48:02:602     932    7b0 Agent     * Network state: Connected
2015-06-02  10:48:02:633     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  10:48:02:633     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing global settings cache  ***********
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent     * Endpoint Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent     * WSUS server: <NULL>
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent     * WSUS status server: <NULL>
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent     * Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2015-06-02  10:48:04:118     932    7b0 Agent     * Windows Update access disabled: No
2015-06-02  10:48:04:165     932    7b0 WuTask  WuTaskManager delay initialize completed successfully..
2015-06-02  10:48:04:633     932    7b0 Report  WARNING: Failed to initialize event uploader for new server {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} with hr = 8024043d.
2015-06-02  10:48:04:633     932    7b0 Report  CWERReporter::Init succeeded
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing Windows Update Agent  ***********
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 DnldMgr Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 AU  ###########  AU: Initializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 AU  AIR Mode is disabled
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 AU    # Approval type: Scheduled (User preference)
2015-06-02  10:48:04:649     932    7b0 AU    # Auto-install minor updates: Yes (User preference)
2015-06-02  10:48:04:665     932    7b0 AU    # ServiceTypeDefault: Service 117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782 Approval type: (Scheduled)
2015-06-02  10:48:04:665     932    7b0 AU    # Will interact with non-admins (Non-admins are elevated (User preference))
2015-06-02  10:48:04:665     932    7b0 AU  WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80070032
2015-06-02  10:48:04:680     932    7b0 AU  AU finished delayed initialization
2015-06-02  10:48:04:680     932    7b0 AU  OOBE is in progress, so cannot perform Accelerated Install
2015-06-02  10:48:05:227     932    bec DnldMgr Asking handlers to reconcile their sandboxes
2015-06-02  10:48:05:727     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2015-06-02  10:48:06:775     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 4.
2015-06-02  10:48:09:197     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2015-06-02  10:48:09:275     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 4.
2015-06-02  10:48:26:995     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2015-06-02  10:48:26:995     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  10:48:27:136     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2015-06-02  10:48:27:277     932    7b0 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 4.
2015-06-02  10:50:48:108     932    50c IdleTmr Incremented idle timer priority operation counter to 1
2015-06-02  10:50:55:328     932    974 AU  Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
2015-06-02  10:50:55:328     932    974 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2015-06-02  10:50:55:328     932    974 AU  Triggering Online detection (interactive)
2015-06-02  10:50:55:344     932    7b0 AU  Windows OOBE is still in progress. AU deferring detection
2015-06-02  10:50:55:344     932    7b0 AU  WARNING: BeginDetection failed, hr:0x8024a008
2015-06-02  10:50:55:344     932    7b0 AU  All AU searches complete.
2015-06-02  10:50:55:344     932    7b0 AU    # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 8024a008
2015-06-02  10:50:55:344     932    7b0 AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2015-06-02 09:20:55
2015-06-02  10:50:55:359     932    7b0 AU  OOBE is in progress, so cannot perform Accelerated Install
2015-06-02  11:01:18:339     932    7b0 AU  ###########  AU: Uninitializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2015-06-02  11:01:18:340     932    7b0 WuTask  Uninit WU Task Manager
2015-06-02  11:01:18:478     932    7b0 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2015-06-02  11:01:18:479    2456    16cc    Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.9.9600.16384, tz: +0200)  ===========
2015-06-02  11:01:18:479    2456    16cc    Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sdiagnhost.exe
2015-06-02  11:01:18:479    2456    16cc    Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wuapi.dll
2015-06-02  11:01:18:479    2456    16cc    COMAPI  WARNING: Received service shutdown/self-update notification.
2015-06-02  11:01:18:707     932    7b0 Service *********
2015-06-02  11:01:18:708     932    7b0 Service **  END  **  Service: Service exit [Exit code = 0x240001]
2015-06-02  11:01:18:708     932    7b0 Service *************
2015-06-02  11:01:19:709     932    78c Service *************
2015-06-02  11:01:19:709     932    78c Service ** START **  Service: Service startup
2015-06-02  11:01:19:709     932    78c Service *********
2015-06-02  11:01:19:719     932    78c Agent     * WU client version 7.9.9600.16422
2015-06-02  11:01:19:720     932    78c Agent     * Base directory: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
2015-06-02  11:01:19:720     932    78c Agent     * Access type: No proxy
2015-06-02  11:01:19:720     932    78c Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 4.
2015-06-02  11:01:19:720     932    78c Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  11:01:19:720     932    78c Agent     * Network state: Connected
2015-06-02  11:01:19:726     932    78c Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 4.
2015-06-02  11:01:19:726     932    78c Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing global settings cache  ***********
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent     * Endpoint Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent     * WSUS server: <NULL>
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent     * WSUS status server: <NULL>
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent     * Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2015-06-02  11:01:19:753     932    7a4 Agent     * Windows Update access disabled: No
2015-06-02  11:01:19:762     932    7a4 WuTask  WuTaskManager delay initialize completed successfully..
2015-06-02  11:01:19:766     932    7a4 Report  WARNING: Failed to initialize event uploader for new server {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} with hr = 8024043d.
2015-06-02  11:01:19:766     932    7a4 Report  CWERReporter::Init succeeded
2015-06-02  11:01:19:766     932    7a4 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing Windows Update Agent  ***********
2015-06-02  11:01:19:766     932    7a4 DnldMgr Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2015-06-02  11:01:19:767     932    7a4 AU  ###########  AU: Initializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2015-06-02  11:01:19:767     932    81c DnldMgr Asking handlers to reconcile their sandboxes
2015-06-02  11:01:19:767     932    7a4 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2015-06-02  11:01:19:804     932    7a4 AU  AIR Mode is disabled
2015-06-02  11:01:19:804     932    7a4 AU    # Approval type: Scheduled (User preference)
2015-06-02  11:01:19:804     932    7a4 AU    # Auto-install minor updates: Yes (User preference)
2015-06-02  11:01:19:804     932    7a4 AU    # ServiceTypeDefault: Service 117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782 Approval type: (Scheduled)
2015-06-02  11:01:19:804     932    7a4 AU    # Will interact with non-admins (Non-admins are elevated (User preference))
2015-06-02  11:01:19:814     932    7a4 AU  WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80070032
2015-06-02  11:01:19:833     932    7a4 AU  AU finished delayed initialization
2015-06-02  11:01:19:834     932    7a4 AU  OOBE is in progress, so cannot perform Accelerated Install
2015-06-02  11:01:19:852     932    7a4 IdleTmr Incremented idle timer priority operation counter to 1
```

Can I fix this without having to restore my Windows installation?

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/a/918338/138343).

Comment: I have run the four command lines, all the opérations are completed successfully but my problem persists.

Comment: Finally, if the PowerShell script Get-WUInstall run for a long time, it succeed to install a lot of updates (~150).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to run Windows updates in Audit mode or the OOBE has not completed, which is why it fails.

I found the following in your log

*Windows OOBE is still in progress.  AU deferring detection.*

*WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 8024a008*

*OOBE is in progress, so cannot perform Accelerated Install.*

.

"the OS has not completed OOBE"

**[Source](http://www.chris123nt.com/2014/02/15/windows-update-in-audit-mode-on-windows-8-1/)**

[Some possibilities on repairing this issue in this thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/40594-63-audit-mode), since we do not know why your PC is in audit mode the solution could be one of many.

Comment: Thank you, Moab. You seems to be right, the problem is my computer is in OOBE mode. Now I'm looking for fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I come back to give you the way I have solve my OOBE problem :

1 ) When I tried to use the sysprep utility into my console, the command wasn't recognized but I succeed to use it directly from it's folder "c:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe \OOBE \reboot".

2 ) On reboot, my computer run the OOBE configuration (I create a temporary local user account to complete it) and finally block on the last step with the finalisation screen.

3 ) When the computer has been blocked on the finalisation script I have to use the "Ctrl + F10" command shortcut to access a terminal.

4 ) Type the "tasklist" command to list all the process running with there PID. There must be 2 cmd.exe process, the one about the current used terminal and the second one used by OOBE process. Note the PID (4 digits number) of this 2 cmd.exe processes ( PID1 and PID2) and type this command "taskkill \PID PID1 \PID PID2" replacing PID1 and PID2 by the real values. The OOBE must terminate and the login screen must appears.

5 ) At this point everything would be fixed, check windows updates process and log, if it's ok you can delete the temporary local account.

PS : There was some other problems on my computers, I was not looking for fixing it because it was not blocking or disturbing. I was not able to custom my account avatar or to custom the picture on the login screen. This problems have been solved with OOBE fix too.