# Can't open Task Scheduler in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, task-scheduler

When I click **Task Scheduler** in *Administrative Tools* in my Windows 8.1, nothing happens. Task Scheduler does not launch. How to fix it?

*EDIT:*
When i try to launch Task Scheduler it seems like it's going to open, because there is a **busy** mouse cursor and the currently active window loses focus for a moment, but nothing happens next, nothing appears.

Comment: Does `Win+R (Run dialog) > taskschd.msc` do anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Comment: Does Event Viewer show any related errors?

Comment: Event Viewer doesn't open either. The same thing happens as with Task Scheduler (busy cursor and focus switch).

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/a/918338/138343) and let me know.

Comment: When I run: Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth 

I get this error:

Error: 0x800f0906
The source files could not be downloaded.
Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required t
o restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077
 
 But there is nothing about /source parameter under that link.

Comment: Try `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:X:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess` where X: is the drive where the Win8.1 ISO/DVD is mounted.

Comment: I have preinstalled Windows 8.1 on my laptop. I don't have DVD.

Comment: You can [download a copy from MS](http://superuser.com/a/747579/138343). Point is, you need a source to replace the damaged files. If it's unable to download them from Windows Update for some reason then you need to point to a WIM instead.

Comment: Ok, I will download it. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: There is no Install.wim in Sources directory, there are only install.exe and install.esd

Comment: This is from the ISO downloaded using the link provided above? What a pain. The DVD contains the WIM. I suppose [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-easily-convert-install-esd-to-install-wim/) should help.

Comment: /RestoreHealth completed successfully I run sfc /scannow next, but still no effect. So there are several tools from Administrative Tools that don't open. Most of them do open normally.

Comment: Do the logs still show errors? Do the Tools open if you create a new local account with admin rights?

Comment: Yes! There are some errors from "sfc /scannow" and that can be the answer. This is the log file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79572898/cbs.log

Comment: Looks like `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Task Scheduler.lnk` is still corrupted. Perhaps others too. Ok, try this. Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools` and extract the [contents of my dir](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3KdjrLI2/0/blob?download) to it. Remember to right-click each shortcut and see if it needs to be *Unblocked*. Then try all the Tools once again and let me know.

Comment: Nothing changed. But if "Win+R (Run dialog) > taskschd.msc" didn't work then it looks like other problem then link in the Start Menu. File c:\Windows\System32\taskschd.ms exists.