# No apps work anymore (Win 8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I can't open any app anymore, except for the store, but I can't install any apps anymore. I always get error 0x8007064a when I try to install apps.
How can I fix this problem and what is it caused by?

Answer (score 0):

In the Run dialog (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) type **WSReset.exe** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot and try running/updating your apps again.

If that doesn't work then go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting` and click on *Fix problems with Windows Update* and then *Try troubleshooting as an administrator*:

[image: 1]

When the troubleshooter's done its job reboot and try running/updating your apps again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it unfortunately didn't work for me.

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/a/918338/138343) helps.