# Windows Defender Service keeps stopping

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, services, malware, windows-defender

Windows defender service keeps stopping all the time. After enabling it, it only runs for a couple of seconds but then stops automatically. I don't know what's the reason but I suspect malware infection since Google Chrome now doesn't install extensions, giving me the `NETWORK_FAILED` error. I am running Windows 8.1 Pro on a 64-bit machine.

What to do ?

Comment: If you suspect malware have you tried scanning using anything other than Defender?

Comment: Yes, I tried [Adware Cleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/), [TDSSKiller](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/TDSSKiller), [Software Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/srt/) and [Junkware Removal Tool](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/junkware-removal-tool/). All didn't work except that last one, which found some suspicious files but after deleting them, nothing changed.

Comment: [Check](http://superuser.com/a/918338/138343) your OS for corruption.

Comment: Did you got any error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Microsoft Community I found a interesting post about that, [that](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/wiki/protect_defender-protect_start/problems-starting-windows-defender-in-windows/808253bb-db89-4db9-a4e5-1c91a86489e9) show you can try to troubleshoot this problem. Just try one after the other.

```
1. Restart your PC
2. Remove existing antivirus and antispyware software
3. Scan your PC for malwares
4. SFC scan
5. Clean Boot
6. Restart Security Center Service
7. Delete conflicting Registry Entry
```

Besides aspect (3), did you also tried the other ways?

If thas wasn't enoght, [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=windows%20defender%20troubleshoot%20windows%208.1) gives you many other instructions for troubleshooting Windwos Defender problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Windows 10. To fix it, I had to uninstall Spybot. Windows Defender is now working as intended.